# Copying from one "not null" column to another gives a "Cannot insert null value into column."

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm currently trying to copy all data from one table to another as the second table is ordered a bit differently I'm using the following SQL script to do so:

```
USE LoanersTest
DROP TABLE LoanerItems1
CREATE TABLE LoanerItems1
(
LoanerKey INT NOT NULL UNIQUE 
,BCPartNumber VARCHAR(255)  NULL 
,Manufacturer VARCHAR(255)  NULL 
,Model VARCHAR(255)  NULL 
,Modality INT NOT NULL UNIQUE
,Status INT  NOT NULL UNIQUE
,Location INT  NOT NULL UNIQUE
,ShelvingKey INT NOT NULL UNIQUE
,CalDate VARCHAR(255)  NULL 
,CalDue VARCHAR(255)  NULL 
,BCID VARCHAR(255)  NULL 
,SerialNumber VARCHAR(255)  NULL 
,AssetTag VARCHAR(255)  NULL 
,LoanTerm VARCHAR(255)  NULL 
,PartNumber VARCHAR(255)  NULL 
,Notes VARCHAR(255)  NULL 
,CriticalNotes VARCHAR(255)  NULL 
,ShippingNotes VARCHAR(255)  NULL 
,ReceivingNotes VARCHAR(255)  NULL 
,Description VARCHAR(255)  NULL 
,Details VARCHAR(255)  NULL 
,Attachments VARCHAR(255)  NULL 
,Manuals VARCHAR(255)  NULL 
,PRIMARY KEY (LoanerKey) 
)
INSERT INTO LoanerItems1 (LoanerKey)
  SELECT LoanerKey FROM LoanerItems

INSERT INTO LoanerItems1 (BCPartNumber)
  SELECT BCPartNumber FROM LoanerItems

INSERT INTO LoanerItems1 (Manufacturer)
  SELECT Manufacturer FROM LoanerItems

INSERT INTO LoanerItems1 (Model)
  SELECT Model FROM LoanerItems

INSERT INTO LoanerItems1 (Modality)
  SELECT Modality FROM LoanerItems

INSERT INTO LoanerItems1 (Status)
  SELECT Status FROM LoanerItems

INSERT INTO LoanerItems1 (Location)
  SELECT Location FROM LoanerItems

INSERT INTO LoanerItems1 (ShelvingKey)
  SELECT ShelvingKey FROM LoanerItems

INSERT INTO LoanerItems1 (CalDate)
  SELECT CalDate FROM LoanerItems

INSERT INTO LoanerItems1 (CalDue)
  SELECT CalDue FROM LoanerItems

INSERT INTO LoanerItems1 (BCID)
  SELECT BCID FROM LoanerItems

INSERT INTO LoanerItems1 (SerialNumber)
  SELECT SerialNumber FROM LoanerItems

INSERT INTO LoanerItems1 (AssetTag)
  SELECT AssetTag FROM LoanerItems

INSERT INTO LoanerItems1 (LoanTerm)
  SELECT LoanTerm FROM LoanerItems

INSERT INTO LoanerItems1 (PartNumber)
  SELECT PartNumber FROM LoanerItems

INSERT INTO LoanerItems1 (Notes)
  SELECT Notes FROM LoanerItems

INSERT INTO LoanerItems1 (CriticalNotes)
  SELECT CriticalNotes FROM LoanerItems

INSERT INTO LoanerItems1 (ShippingNotes)
  SELECT ShippingNotes FROM LoanerItems

INSERT INTO LoanerItems1 (ReceivingNotes)
  SELECT ReveivingNotes FROM LoanerItems

INSERT INTO LoanerItems1 (Description)
  SELECT Description FROM LoanerItems

INSERT INTO LoanerItems1 (Details)
  SELECT Details FROM LoanerItems

INSERT INTO LoanerItems1 (Attachments)
  SELECT Attachments FROM LoanerItems

INSERT INTO LoanerItems1 (Manuals)
  SELECT Manuals FROM LoanerItems
```

The first table is formatted exactly the same (though the columns are ordered a bit differently) and contains around 80 records. None of the records contain a null value and yet executing this statement returns the following:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Modality', table 'LoanersTest.dbo.LoanerItems1'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

And

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'LoanerKey', table 'LoanersTest.dbo.LoanerItems1'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

The values in `LoanerKey` are essentially 1, 2, 3, 4, 5... 85, 86, 87. The modality column contains, for the time being, the same values. Again neither column contains nulls and yet this error is returned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't insert individual columns. Insert all the columns in one query.

Like

```
INSERT INTO LoanerItems1 (LoanerKey, BCPartNumber, Manufacturer...)
SELECT LoanerKey, BCPartNumber, Manufacturer, ....  FROM LoanerItems
```

When you insert only one column, as you are doing, the other columns will default to NULL, and that is the reason for the error that you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert all of the records at one time.  Your statements are trying to insert an entire row, but only setting one column.  You want this:

```
insert into LoanerItems1
(LoanerKey
,BCPartNumber
,Manufacturer
,Model
,Modality
,Status
,Location
,ShelvingKey
,CalDate
,CalDue
,BCID
,SerialNumber
,AssetTag
,LoanTerm
,PartNumber
,Notes
,CriticalNotes
,ShippingNotes
,ReceivingNotes
,Description
,Details
,Attachments
,Manuals
,BCPartNumber
,Manufacturer
,Model
,Modality
,Status
,Location
,ShelvingKey
,CalDate
,CalDue
,BCID
,SerialNumber
,AssetTag
,LoanTerm
,PartNumber
,Notes
,CriticalNotes
,ShippingNotes
,ReceivingNotes
,Description
,Details
,Attachments
,Manuals)
SELECT LoanerKey
,BCPartNumber
,Manufacturer
,Model
,Modality
,Status
,Location
,ShelvingKey
,CalDate
,CalDue
,BCID
,SerialNumber
,AssetTag
,LoanTerm
,PartNumber
,Notes
,CriticalNotes
,ShippingNotes
,ReceivingNotes
,Description
,Details
,Attachments
,Manuals
,BCPartNumber
,Manufacturer
,Model
,Modality
,Status
,Location
,ShelvingKey
,CalDate
,CalDue
,BCID
,SerialNumber
,AssetTag
,LoanTerm
,PartNumber
,Notes
,CriticalNotes
,ShippingNotes
,ReceivingNotes
,Description
,Details
,Attachments
,Manuals
from LoanerItems
```

Comment: You're missing a `SELECT` statement.

Comment: No I wasn't, but I made it all CAPS to stand out better.

Comment: Oh... you're right! Sorry about that. I use indentation to help with that problem.